# Multiple-choice, spaced-repetition flashcards for Android

Tags: android, educational, flashcard

I'm looking for a flashcard testing / learning app for Android with the following features:

1. Supports multiple-choice questions and randomizes the order of the answers when it presents the card.
2. Uses a spaced repetition system, so I don't waste time revising cards which I already know well.
3. Allows import of flashcard data from a prepared file. (The exact format of the file isn't important: I can always wrangle my data into the required form somehow.)
4. Works offline.

It would also be nice if the program were Free Software / Open Source, but this is not essential.

AnkiDroid, my usual choice for flashcards, is no good to me in this case because it doesn't support multiple-choice questions.

Comment: I have not tried any of those myself, but [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/school_flashcards) has some potential candidates. [Karteikasten](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.devmax.englischvokabeltrainer) should meet most (if not all) your requirements, [NoteText](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/myapplication.flashcards) could fit as well.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the suggestions, and for the link to your app listing site -- looks like a very useful resource. Karteikasten comes very close but doesn't randomize answer order. NoteText doesn't seem to offer multiple choice at all. I'll look through the rest of the listed apps and see if I can find something more suitable.

Comment: Exactly the randomizing was what I wasn't sure about. If you find something else that matches, please [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Also consider contacting the author of Karteikasten to include this feature (I'm no dev, but I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to implement, while being a useful addition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet, but it claims to be what you need.  (If "Works Offline" means on Android and/or Windows)

https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/947272864

It's a flashcard template for the Windows and Android clients for Anki.  Anki inherently provides spaced repetition. The template adds the multiple choice randomization.  Once your deck is set up, it works offline, and syncs with the Anki cloud service once you're back online.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like exactly what I was looking for. I don't have time to evaluate it right now but will come back later and mark as accepted if it works as advertised.

Comment: I just tried it out. Fantastic, seems to work flawlessly both on desktop and Android. I had been vaguely aware that Anki had some degree of Javascript support but I had no idea that things like this were possible. It's the perfect solution for me since I'm already using Anki. Thank you once again.

Comment: "This shared item is no longer available"